# There is no lib folder and no pubspec.yaml file

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, lib, pubspec.yaml

I updated my android then when I open new flutter project there is no lib folder and no `pubspec.yaml` file:

[image]

and these errors occurred:

[image]

I tried to redownload gradle but the errors still there
I searched for solution  but I did not found any helpful answer

Comment: Your opening the wrong directory. do not open the `Android` folder instead open the Flutter project directory

Answer (score 1):

Your opening the wrong directory. Do not open the `Android` folder instead open the Flutter project directory.

You might also just be displaying the incorrect view. So select it:

[image]

However, regarding the error you recieved, not neccessaraly does it have to do with opening the incorrect directory, you can google for your answer.